# Проблема с подключением файла php

Tags: php, phpstorm

php почему то не видит переменную из подключаемого файла. В чем может быть дело? Понимаю что вопрос глупый, но сам догадаться не могу уже час...[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хорошим тоном считается показывать код форматированным текстом, а не скриншотами.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22476778/phpstorm-undefined-variables-caused-by-include-require

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле вам уже ответили в комментариях, но повторюсь. На самом деле ваша среда не видит переменную, так как большинство из них работает через composer и так понимают что-где.

В вашем случае, надо либо сказать шторму, чтобы не ругался, либо в начале файла "задокументировать" переменную

```
/** @var resource $link DB Connection */
```